# Is there a way to use git to automatically update a library from Github into an Android Studio Project?

Tags: github, android-studio, mpandroidchart

I know how to clone a GitHub project as a new Android Studio project, but I have not yet found a way of directly importing a GitHub library project as a library into my existing Android Studio project without either

1) using external version control software (such as standalone git) or

2) downloading the library as a zip and importing it manually (thus losing the ability to pull the latest updates without repeating this step)

Is there a way to import GitHub library projects (as for example the MPAndroidChart engine) into my Android Studio project with Android Studio managing the version control to stay up to date?

Usually I just go to gradleplease.appspot.com and look for a gradle dependency, but not all libraries are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a GitHub library project into your build using [JitPack](https://jitpack.io).

For example, for MPAndroidChart it would be: https://jitpack.io/#PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

And, you can also find it in the [usage section](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart#usage) of the library on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gradle you can use the  maven repository, that has the MPandroidchart library.
[http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|mpandroidchart](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cmpandroidchart)